# Trying to insert new column which is combination of two different columns i.e race and ethnicity

Tags: r

For demographic analysis of state I want to compare race and ethnicity and want to find out how many people are hispanic, non-hispanic and others

```
hsg.ppl2$XYZ <- for(i in 1:100)
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 1) { "NHWht" } else if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 2) { "NHBlack" } else 
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & (hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 6 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 7)) {"NHAsian" } else
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & (hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 3 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 4 |hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 5 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 8 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 9)) {"NHOther" } else
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] >= 1) {"HISP"} 
else {NA}
```

I am getting XYZ actual column as null

Comment: You will increase the probability of getting a response providing a reproductive take a look at this post: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XYZ <- NULL
for(i in 1:100) {
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 1) { XYZ[i] <- "NHWht" } else if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 2) { XYZ[i] <- "NHBlack" } else 
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & (hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 6 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 7)) {XYZ[i] <- "NHAsian" } else
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] == 1 & (hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 3 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 4 |hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 5 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 8 | hsg.ppl2$RAC1P[i] == 9)) {XYZ[i] <- "NHOther" } else
if (hsg.ppl2$HISP[i] >= 1) {XYZ[i] <- "HISP"} 
else {XYZ[i] <- NA}
}
hsg.ppl2$XYZ <- XYZ
```